# how to create a new AVD in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-virtual-device

I have a problem in creating a new android virtual device in eclipse I have a window with this information needed :
AVD name ,
Device ,
Target ,
CPU/ABI ,
Keyboard ,
Skin ,
Front Camera ,
Back Camera ,
Memory Options ,
Internal Storge ,
SD Card ,
Emulation Options ,
and an OK button .

Instead of the window which I see in the tutorials that needs just this info :
Name ,
Target ,
CPU/ABI ,
SD Card ,
Snapshot ,
Skin ,
Hardware ,
and Create AVD button .

And in my window I don't know what is the device option should I select + what ever I selected the OK button never be available ! what should I do ? 
please help me , thank you .

Comment: Screenshots would be cool.

Comment: I am a new member in this website and add images not allowed to me , I tried to add a screenshots and it doesn't work , I am sorry .

Comment: Kindly add more information about eclipse version that you used and extra screen shots

Comment: I am using "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" the Version: Juno Service Release 1 .
and as I said I can't add images :(

Comment: @rand Host the image on another site and link em here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

May be the following will help :

[image: Window -> Android Virtual Device Manager]

[image: Device Definitions]

[image: Create new device]

Then start the emulator

Comment: thank you this is really helpful , but please what should the screen size be?

Comment: You can check the device that you want to simulate its size screen on gsmarena.com for example, and put its screen resolution heightXwidth and the whole screen size in inches such as 4.7 inch as mentioned in the second screenshot above

Answer (score 5):

Try to create an AVD with the `monitor.bat` in the `tools-folder`, that worked out for me!

Comment: no but i keep having this error with different machines. only with the ADT (= android developer tools) it seems to work, not with native eclipse plus sd + adt

Answer (score 1):

They most probably have changed some AVD settings. As for your second question regarding what options you should select: Don't make a very tiny SD card. Anything above 100mb should work fine.  As for target choose the android version you've downloaded a system image for using the SDK.

I don't understand what you mean by "not be available", but if its the OK button its because you have no target platform.

If you mean, that the emulator won't start up, give it some time. You can even put the emulator in snapshot mode so it will open right where it last left off, saving you time.

Comment: I mean that what ever I put the options I can't press the OK button .. I tried many options and it doesn't work , please see the links I added now in the question .

Answer (score 1):

Try Window -> Android SDK Manager. 
update your Android SDK Tools and Android SDK Platform-tools to the latest version

Answer (score 1):

if u cant click the ok button,try running avd manager outside eclipse.it worked for me as i encountered very same problem...later choose that device from avd manager using eclipse.it will run the stimulator

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an AVD in Eclipse you need to do this:

1. Go to Window -> Android Virtual Device Manager
2. Then you need to give a name and select the platform that you want (Target option)
3. Then the button "Create AVD" activates.

The other options you can let them unmodified.

Answer (score 0):

another alternative is install ARM EABI system image from sdk of your respective android version,then restart eclipse.it will  now allow you to click OK button.hope this helps you...

Answer (score 0):

add ADT to your Eclipse Project and click on avd icon in IDE to open avd manager then create a new device and also new virtual devices

Answer (score 0):

For me, the "OK" button was disabled because I had spaces in the AVD name. After removing the spaces from the name, the "OK" button was enabled.[image]