# How to change android virtual device?

Tags: android

I am using eclipse 32-bit version at the time of initiation.
I choose tablet as android virtual device,but now I want to change my virtual device,so,please tell the procedure how to change the android virtual device?

Comment: how-to-create-a-new-avd-in-eclipse - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317789/how-to-create-a-new-avd-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, click on Run in the toolbar then Run Configurations. Select your application and click on the Target tag. You can then select which AVD to use or set it to manual so it asks you each time you run the app.

Answer (score 0):

"Run As" -> Run Configurations -> Target
Select your new Android Virtual Device and It's done :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use genymotion. Maybe, install the app is not so easy because you need also install a virtual machine but that emulator/s are working much better than the oficial. Specially when you need run the app frecuently: the app will be loaded faster than using the official one.

http://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: Where you can set deviceId its paid

Comment: you don't like genymotion?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Your required device then you can change configuration from

[image]

Then check the selected radio button [image]

Or if you don't have

Just Create a new Virtual Device from Virtual Device Manager

[image]

click on Second Icon
Then

[image]

You will be either asked for configuration or

[image]

You can select predefined configuration

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change Run configurations for your project from Run->configurations then choose what you want to be as the target

There are 3 options:
1- Always prompt pick device(I think this might be helpful to you)

2- Launch on all active devices

3- Automatically pick device