# INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR on installing a game on AVD

Tags: android

I tried to install a game in my AVD(Android Virtual Device).
Using adb install xxx.apk I got above error.

I set 2 GB Internal Storage but in AVD I have only 190MB and I set 3 GB SD Card.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new avd

[how to create a new AVD in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317789/how-to-create-a-new-avd-in-eclipse)

http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/how-to-create-android-avd-emulator-in-eclipse/

try out the following procedure

```
copy your apk file into platform-tools of your android sdk it can be like C:\android-sdk\platform-tools.

now go to command prompt and change the path to platform-tools the write a command as follows
cmd -- adb install (appName).apk 

it takes few minutes and gives you success response in cmd prompt..
```

and there were many links to guide you, you can go with this reference

http://www.android.pk/blog/general/how-to-install-apk-files-on-android-emulator/

Comment: Didn't work for me. I tried to create a new AVD, to decode the apk, change de Manifest.xml (preferExternal to auto change) and recode it. Signed it with an auto-signed certificate ... I still got the INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR.  I'm wondering if it's because this is an hybrid application ...