# "No AVD Available" Message after installing Eclipse and Android SDK

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop andriod application.

For that, I installed eclipse, and Android SDK.

However when I want to add new andriod virtual device, it is showing  "**no avd available**" Message.

Below is the screenshot of the project. Don't really know what to do .

I have re-install Android SDK, but still facing the same issue.

[image: Screen shot of project]

Comment: Where's the screenshot??

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have downloaded the system images of the API processor in your SDK, specially of the API you are compiling your project in.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously.

You haven't created an AVD, then how will it show you one ?

There is an option `Create`, (which is already highlighted in your screenshot with blue color). Follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317789/how-to-create-a-new-avd-in-eclipse) for a detailed answer on stack overflow (and try searching on SO before asking a question) or follow [this one](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html) which takes you to `developer.android`'s website.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue since I was the first time user but this solution worked for me . try it
Windows>Avdmanager>device definition tab>select any of the available device>Create AVD option will come alive> click on it> fill the details this time you'll get OK button!!