# A Repairable Android Virtual Machine. An Android Virtual Device that failed to load

Tags: android-activity, eclipse-adt

I am trying for a simple hello world application,but i'm stuck at creating Android Virtual Device to run the application. I have referred to other posts also but the solutions didn't help me. I used WVGA800 skin,3.7 FWVGA slider, Android 2.2-API level 8, and ARM(armeabi) to create AVD

Comment: can you tell me what is exact problem you are facing ?

Comment: still facing the problem ? if so tell me I will help you out

Answer (score 0):

May be the following will help :

[image: Window -> Android Virtual Device Manager]

[image: Device Definitions]

[image: Create new device]

Then start the AVD

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14318236/5132539)