# OS Doesn't fit emulator AVD

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, android-virtual-device

I am new to Phonegap and Android development in general. I created a new project using node.js and cordova, and later imported it to eclipse.

I am trying to run the default app created using [this](http://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/empezando-phonegap/) guide, but the problem I encounter is that Android OS doesn't fit my AVD emulator screen. I've tried scaling the emulator, using different skins, checking "Scale display to real size" and setting different screen sizes and monitor dpi and still can't get my problem solved.

Hope the following pictures help illustrate my problem.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: select the proper size of display while creating amulator

Comment: could you please tell me how? Because I don't see any information related to screen size while creating an AVD. Thanks

Comment: have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317789/how-to-create-a-new-avd-in-eclipse) post

Comment: @ManuelS. that tutorial is outdated. DO NOT USE IT. Find another tutorial. The tutorial is using `PhoneGap 3.3.0-0.18.0`. Phonegap is not `5.4.0` [Documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/es/5.4.0/index.html) and [CLI Reference](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/es/5.4.0/index.html)

Comment: @Mohit, tried what the posts says and that didn't help. I'll follow JessesMonroy650's advice and start from scratch with a more updated tutorial. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score -2):

I advise you to test the Genymotion.

https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download

It may be faster;